# How to convert TextView.attributedText in HTML format in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

In this textview i edit text by rich-text-editor

[image]

Comment: Do you really think we can help you having only that strange image?

Comment: @NSNoob done ;)

Answer (score 0):

TextView just can show Simple Text.
you can show html in UIWebView.

Comment: TextView can show any text. Including an HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSAttributedString *articleText = _txtView.attributedText;

NSDictionary *documentAttributes = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

NSData *htmlData = [articleText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, articleText.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for a 'WYSIWYG' text view.

You could try and search for `WYSIWYG html ios` online and see what library suits you best. `ZSSRichTextEditor` for example is a rich text editor for iOS. You simply convert a `UITextView` and get extra buttons that change the output html. (Bold, underline, colour, etc.)

Comment: NSString *str = textView.attributedText ;